# postgreSQL- get error of invalid input value for enum

Tags: sql, postgresql

table:

```
create type status as enum ('new_ride', 'ride_assigned', 'ride_start', 'ride_end', 'ride_cancelled');

create table ride_status (
id int primary key,
ride_id int,
created_at timestamp,
status status,
status_timestamp timestamp,
foreign key (ride_id) references ride (id));

insert into ride_status values
(1, 1, '2020-04-01 11:00:00', 'ride_start', '2020-04-01 11:05:00'),
(2, 1, null, 'ride_end', '2020-04-01 11:15:00'),
(3, 2, null, 'ride_start', '2020-04-02 12:06:00'),
(4, 2, null, 'ride_end', '2020-04-02 12:25:00'),
(5, 3, null, 'ride_start', '2020-04-03 14:05:00'),
(6, 3, null, 'ride_end', '2020-04-03 14:35:00'),
(7, 4, null, 'ride_start', '2020-04-04 11:10:00'),
(8, 4, null, 'ride_end', '2020-04-04 11:35:30'),
(9, 5, null, 'ride_start', '2020-04-04 15:05:00'),
(10, 5, null, 'ride_end', '2020-04-04 15:15:45');
```

the enum and table are created successfully, but when executing `insert into`, get following error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input value for enum status: "ride_start"
LINE 2: (1, 1, '2020-04-01 11:00:00', 'ride_start', '2020-04-01 11:0...
                                      ^
SQL state: 22P02
Character: 62
```

any idea of this error? thanks

UPDATE:
with help from here, I think this is postgresql version 12 that has this issue. when I tried this in v11 the original solution also works. As a work around for v12, just rename the enum to a different name from the column name. Thanks for all the help here!

Comment: [works fine for me](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pwhpfbH5PkKL6pWxTSzh56/0)

Comment: when I click run, it show "an unexpected error occured".

Comment: Change the version to something other than 12. Something is wrong with their v12 database; not even `SELECT version()` (in the right box, with nothing else in the left box) works, look: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dJofBpY3zVu3kr7XYb9jqa/0 screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QAcD.png

Comment: yeap, I retried on v11 and it worked! so I think it's version 12 that has this issue. I also checked the version in my pc it's v12.2!

Comment: No, something is wrong with db-fiddle.com's v12 database, nothing to do with your query. Look, it can't even tell me its version: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QAcD.png

Comment: It works fine in v12 on a different fiddle site: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ec22b5057b636d97526103223e6b4eb2 - credit: HWNN

Comment: *"As a work around for v12, just rename the enum to a different name from the column name"* - not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is `status status` in your create statement, you should assign different column name then ENUM type name.

Try this one, it should work as expected -- take a look here [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/cb488)

```
create type r_status as enum ('new_ride', 'ride_assigned', 'ride_start', 'ride_end', 'ride_cancelled');

create table ride_status 
(
    id int primary key,
    ride_id int,
    created_at timestamp,
    status r_status,
    status_timestamp timestamp,
    foreign key (ride_id) references ride (id)
);
```

Comment: While that is indeed a questionable naming convention, I don't think it's the cause of the error

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you can check my sqlfiddle.

Comment: I don't doubt that your solution works, but the original solution works as well: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ec22b5057b636d97526103223e6b4eb2

Comment: yours work, but when I change back to my solution in your dbfiddle it also works. weird that it just doesn't work in my pc. and in my pc I followed your solution and it works for me. this is still a mystery but I'm glad I'm unblocked. Thanks for the help!